# Can I display the message on the desktop before execution of test case in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to show the message like "In this test case I am logging into my account" before launching the browser something like a pop up message or some plain text. I know I can print this statement in console using System.out.print() but i need to display this message on the desktop screen itself.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: why dont you use swing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852560/how-to-make-popup-window-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this for years. I added a main method so you can try it out in one class file:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Popup extends JPanel {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Popup a = new Popup();
            a.popup("Title", "Message");
        }

        public void popup(String title, String message) {
            String markup = "<html><font color=#0033CC size=+1>" + message + "</html>";
            JLabel l = new JLabel(markup);
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridLayout(0, 1));
            p.add(l);
            JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
            f.setContentPane(p);
            f.setSize(600, 200);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < (startTime + 5000)) {
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
            f.setVisible(false);
            f.dispose();
            f = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Oracle Java Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) you can use following code for your dialog message :

```
//default title and icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Your text");
```